# failing to configure a dhcp scope under Oracle Virtualbox

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I've got a problem configuring a link between WS 2008 and Windows 7 both running as virtual machines (under Oracle VM 4.2.something). Static addresses do well, with both `ping 192.168.1.2` (client) and `ping 192.168.1.1` (server) working seamlessly (from each other & the host machine(its address is `192.168.1.3`)).

However, when I try to add a DHCP scope, it all goes amiss:

1. The scope is 192.168.1.x - 192.168.1.y. DHCP refuses to do anything because "scopes overlap" (*even though the hypervisor's own DHCP is off*).
2. The scope is any other, say 192.100.1.x - 192.100.1.y. DHCP is happy but doesn't give out any addresses (and pinging any of them fails.)
3. When I set machine addresses temporarily anywhere but 192.168.1.x, set the DHCP to these octets and then change them back (so that the DHCP scope and the server address are in one subnet), <strike>all hell is let loose</strike> the server stops seeing that DHCP is running even though it actually is (`net start dhcpserver` complains about the service already having been launched).

So, what to do? How to set up the hypervisor and the DHCP scope so that DHCP could actually assign addresses?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What server is acting as the DHCP server?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 - the one under WS 2008